# Include reducer into combineReducers, something is missing

Tags: react-redux

I'm trying to include 4 more reducers into my app, once included my app start to fail.

For test purpose, I've included into the combineReducers function only my current reducer, and the app also fail, I think the app doesn't must change or fail doing this change.

In this state the app works

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App/index';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { defaultreducer } from './_reducers/default.reducer';
import config from './config';

const store = createStore(reducer);
```

If I change and include the reducer into combineReducers function the app crash

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { combineReducers, createStore } from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App/index';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import { defaultreducer } from './_reducers/default.reducer';
import config from './config';

const root_reducer = combineReducers({
  reducer: defaultreducer
});

const store = createStore(root_reducer);
```

My reducer

```js
import * as actionTypes from '../store/actions';
import config from './../config';

const initialState = {
  isOpen: [], //for active default menu
  isTrigger: [], //for active default menu, set blank for horizontal
  ...config,
  isFullScreen: false, // static can't change
}

export function defaultreducer(state = initialState, action) {
    let trigger = [];
    let open = [];

    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.COLLAPSE_MENU:
            return {
                ...state,
                collapseMenu: !state.collapseMenu
            };
        case actionTypes.COLLAPSE_TOGGLE:
            if (action.menu.type === 'sub') {
                open = state.isOpen;
                trigger = state.isTrigger;

                const triggerIndex = trigger.indexOf(action.menu.id);
                if (triggerIndex > -1) {
                    open = open.filter(item => item !== action.menu.id);
                    trigger = trigger.filter(item => item !== action.menu.id);
                }

                if (triggerIndex === -1) {
                    open = [...open, action.menu.id];
                    trigger = [...trigger, action.menu.id];
                }
            } else {
                open = state.isOpen;
                const triggerIndex = (state.isTrigger).indexOf(action.menu.id);
                trigger = (triggerIndex === -1) ? [action.menu.id] : [];
                open = (triggerIndex === -1) ? [action.menu.id] : [];
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                isOpen: open,
                isTrigger: trigger
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_CONTENT_LEAVE:
            return {
                ...state,
                isOpen: open,
                isTrigger: trigger,
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_COLLAPSE_LEAVE:
            if (action.menu.type === 'sub') {
                open = state.isOpen;
                trigger = state.isTrigger;

                const triggerIndex = trigger.indexOf(action.menu.id);
                if (triggerIndex > -1) {
                    open = open.filter(item => item !== action.menu.id);
                    trigger = trigger.filter(item => item !== action.menu.id);
                }
                return {
                    ...state,
                    isOpen: open,
                    isTrigger: trigger,
                };
            }
            return {...state};
        case actionTypes.FULL_SCREEN :
            return {
                ...state,
                isFullScreen: !state.isFullScreen
            };
        case actionTypes.FULL_SCREEN_EXIT:
            return {
                ...state,
                isFullScreen: false
            };
        case actionTypes.CHANGE_LAYOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                layout: action.layout
            };
        case actionTypes.CHANGE_PRE_LAYOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                preLayout: action.preLayout
            };
        case actionTypes.LAYOUT_TYPE:
            return {
                ...state,
                layoutType: action.layoutType,
                navBackColor: (action.layoutType === 'dark' && initialState.navBackColor === 'navbar-default') ? 'navbar-dark' : state.navBackColor,
                navBrandColor: (action.layoutType === 'dark' && initialState.navBrandColor === 'brand-default') ? 'brand-dark' : state.navBrandColor,
                navBackImage: initialState.navBackImage,
                headerBackColor: initialState.headerBackColor
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_BACK_COLOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                navBackColor: action.navBackColor,
                navBackImage: initialState.navBackImage,
                navBrandColor: 'brand-default',
                layoutType: (state.layoutType === 'menu-light') ? 'menu-dark' : state.layoutType
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_BACK_IMAGE:
            return {
                ...state,
                layoutType: 'menu-dark',
                navBackImage: action.navBackImage,
                navBrandColor: '',
                navBackColor: ''
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_BRAND_COLOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                navBrandColor: action.navBrandColor
            };
        case actionTypes.HEADER_BACK_COLOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                headerBackColor: action.headerBackColor
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_ICON_COLOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                navIconColor: !state.navIconColor
            };
        case actionTypes.RTL_LAYOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                rtlLayout: !state.rtlLayout
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_FIXED_LAYOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                navFixedLayout: !state.navFixedLayout
            };
        case actionTypes.HEADER_FIXED_LAYOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                headerFixedLayout: !state.headerFixedLayout,
                headerBackColor: (!state.headerFixedLayout && initialState.headerBackColor === 'header-default') ? 'header-blue' : state.headerBackColor,
                navBrandColor: (!state.headerFixedLayout) ? 'brand-default' : initialState.navBrandColor
            };
        case actionTypes.BOX_LAYOUT:
            return {
                ...state,
                boxLayout: !state.boxLayout
            };
        case actionTypes.LAYOUT6_BACKGROUND:
            return {
                ...state,
                layout6Background: action.value.layout6Background,
                layout6BackSize: action.value.layout6BackSize
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_DROPDOWN_ICON:
            return {
                ...state,
                navDropdownIcon: action.navDropdownIcon,
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_LIST_ICON:
            return {
                ...state,
                navListIcon: action.navListIcon,
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_ACTIVE_LIST_COLOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                navActiveListColor: action.navActiveListColor,
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_LIST_TITLE_COLOR:
            return {
                ...state,
                navListTitleColor: action.navListTitleColor,
            };
        case actionTypes.NAV_LIST_TITLE_HIDE:
            return {
                ...state,
                navListTitleHide: !state.navListTitleHide,
            };
        case actionTypes.CONFIG_BLOCK:
            return {
                ...state,
                configBlock: !state.configBlock,
            };
        case actionTypes.RESET:
            return {
                ...state,
                layout: initialState.layout,
                preLayout: initialState.preLayout,
                collapseMenu: initialState.collapseMenu,
                layoutType: initialState.layoutType,
                navIconColor: initialState.navIconColor,
                headerBackColor: initialState.headerBackColor,
                navBackColor: initialState.navBackColor,
                navBrandColor: initialState.navBrandColor,
                navBackImage: initialState.navBackImage,
                rtlLayout: initialState.rtlLayout,
                navFixedLayout: initialState.navFixedLayout,
                headerFixedLayout: initialState.headerFixedLayout,
                boxLayout: initialState.boxLayout,
                navDropdownIcon: initialState.navDropdownIcon,
                navListIcon: initialState.navListIcon,
                navActiveListColor: initialState.navActiveListColor,
                navListTitleColor: initialState.navListTitleColor,
                navListTitleHide: initialState.navListTitleHide,
                layout6Background : initialState.layout6Background
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Even compiling without warnings or errors in terminal I got the next error in my browser

```js
  46 | let navLinkClass = ['nav-link'];
  47 | 
  48 | let navItemClass = ['nav-item', 'pcoded-hasmenu'];
> 49 | const openIndex = isOpen.findIndex(id => id === this.props.collapse.id);
     | ^  50 | if (openIndex > -1) {
  51 |     navItemClass = [...navItemClass, 'active'];
  52 |     if (this.props.layout !== 'horizontal') {
```

My question is, why moving the reducer into the combineReducers function the app crash?

Thanks!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because when you're including just the reducer, your state is a simple object like so:

```
state {
  isOpen: [],
  ....
}
```

When you `combineReducers`, you pass in an object with the following structure:

```
{ stateKey1: reducer, stateKey2: reducer2...etc }
```

`stateKey1` and `stateKey2` are actually substates of your redux apps, which help drive down complexity and keep your components as individual as possible.

in your case, this means that your reducer state will actually be nested one level down, which means your state will now look like:

```
state {
  reducer {
    isOpen: []
    ...
  }
}
```

where, `'reducer'` is the key you give to the object passed as argument to `combineReducers`;
To fix this, wherever you are consuming the redux state as props, access them like so:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({isOpen: state.reducer.isOpen});
```